# How add timestamp to rust stderr

Tags: logging, rust, stderr, rust-tokio

I use tokio for async code and env_logger to stdout.

So in stdout clear when the event took place: `[2023-11-29T02:30:03Z INFO  myapp] connected success`

But in for panic in stderr only: `Error: Io(Os { code: 111, kind: ConnectionRefused, message: "Connection refused" })`

How to make the error log more informative? (timestamp for example)

My code for example

```
use env_logger::{Builder, Target};
use tokio::net::TcpStream;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut builder = Builder::from_default_env();
    builder.target(Target::Stdout);
    builder.init();
    warn!("my test connected");

    TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:3030").await.unwrap();
}
```